# Perfmon: How to get a contiguous trace

Tags: c++, windows, perfmon

The trace of the below code is all broken, not a smooth curve. This is the snippet of my program. My sampling rate is 1 sec and I have tried all possible sampling values. I have also tried the below code using just the PerfSetULongLongCounterValue() and not using Decrement/Increment calls. That also did not help. There must be a way/setting to tell Perfmon that, if the incoming value is 100, 200, 300, 500, 300, 200, 100 draw Sine wave. When I give the sine wave data at 1 sec interval I get disjointed lines. Please help.

```
PerfSetULongLongCounterValue(abcd, GPerfInstance0[0], TOT_MBW_ID, 0);
ULONGLONG counterValue = 0, oldCounterValue = 0;
SYSTEMTIME sysTime;
while (!_kbhit()) {
    counterValue = 30+ (rand() % 10)*100;
    if (counterValue > oldCounterValue) {
        PerfIncrementULongLongCounterValue(abcd, GPerfInstance0[0], TOT_MBW_ID, llabs(counterValue - oldCounterValue));
    } else if (counterValue < oldCounterValue) {
        PerfDecrementULongLongCounterValue(abcd, GPerfInstance0[0], TOT_MBW_ID, llabs(counterValue - oldCounterValue));
    } else {
        PerfSetULongLongCounterValue(abcd, GPerfInstance0[0], TOT_MBW_ID, counterValue);
    }
    GetSystemTime(&sysTime);
    cout << counterValue << ", " << sysTime.wMinute << ":" << sysTime.wSecond << "\n";
    oldCounterValue = counterValue;
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

I was pointed to this sample code:
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/winbase/PerfCounters/Basic/CPP/ucs.c
This does work perfectly however when I tried that same code in my code PerfSetCounterRefValue() errored out with 0x57 INVALID_PARAMETER. So I gave up on that. Atleast the above code works far more and needs somewhere one small tweak. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

MSFT provides a sample code here: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/winbase/PerfCounters/Basic/CPP 
This sample has one issue, I could not get PerfSetCounterRefValue() to work. It complained about ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (0x57). My code does not use it. 
The other problem was using PerfSetULongLongCounterValue(), if I use that instead of PerfIncrementULongLongCounterValue() my trace breaks up do not get contiguous trace.

Ok finally I got it working. Is it the correct/official way? I don't know. In my case it works fine and faithfully traces the value fed to it.

```
ULONGLONG initValue = 0;
ULONGLONG currentValue = 0;
SYSTEMTIME sysTime;
PerfSetULongLongCounterValue(HandleX, PerfInstance, 1, initValue);

while (!_kbhit()) {
    currentValue = (rand() % 10)*100;
    GetSystemTime(&sysTime);
    PerfIncrementULongLongCounterValue(HandleX, PerfInstance, 1, currentValue);
    cout << sysTime.wMinute << ":" << sysTime.wSecond << " " << currentValue << "\n";
    Sleep(1000);
}
return 0;
```